# Why does Keras prepend path information to variable names?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I wanted to make a copy of a Keras variable and assign it a name of my choosing. What I found was that Keras would prepend path information to the name I chose.

```
>>> orig
<tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 32) dtype=float32_ref>
>>> cpy = K.variable(K.get_value(orig), name="copy")

>>> cpy.name
u'training/SGD0/copy:0'
>>> orig.name
u'conv2d_1/kernel:0'
```

I don't understand why the path info was prepended to the name of my copied tensor, but was seemingly not prepended to the original tensor - orig. I'd like to know either the reason this happened, or how to avoid it.

Comment: strange, not reproducible on my system

Answer (score 0):

For reasons I don't entirely understand, Tensorflow seems to look for a '/' as the final character of a variable's name in order to ensure it's unique - lines 4106 - 4117 of tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:

```
try:
  old_stack = self._name_stack
  if not name:  # Both for name=None and name="" we re-set to empty scope.
    new_stack = None
  elif name[-1] == "/":
    new_stack = _name_from_scope_name(name)
  else:
    new_stack = self.unique_name(name)
  self._name_stack = new_stack
  yield "" if new_stack is None else new_stack + "/"
finally:
  self._name_stack = old_stack
```

So, adding a '/' to the end of the variable's name eliminates the path prepending, although the '/' is replaced by a ':0'

```
>>> orig
<tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 32) dtype=float32_ref>
>>> cpy = K.variable(K.get_value(orig), name="copy/")
>>> cpy.name
u'copy:0'
```